# PHP and mysql Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So I am developing a basic website that reports locations of items that are stored in the database. What I am trying to do is create a table of results from the tables stored within phpmyadmin.

What I want is to make each table row a link to another page where the item will be expanded into more detail (individual page result). E.g. person clicks on the row relating to a shop then they will be directed to another page for that shop. So how do I do that using php. See my code below

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
    $ratingStars = "";
    $ratingNo = $row[rating];

    for($i=0; $i<$ratingNo; $i++){
        $ratingStars .= "&#9733; ";
    }

    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<tr id=". $row['id'] .">";
    echo "<td class='lrg-tbl-row'>" . $row["hotspot-name"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='lrgz-tbl-row'>" . $row["address"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='lrg-tbl-row'>" . $row["suburb"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='sml-tbl-row'>" . $ratingStars . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name = 'Submit' value='Text'/>" . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Comment: Make a link that provides the id of the record. On the requested page load data based on that id..

Comment: sorry what do you mean chris85

Answer (score 0):

No need to form submit. Just create a link to go other page. If you want you can encode your id value. also

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
    $ratingStars = "";
    $ratingNo = $row[rating];

    for($i=0; $i<$ratingNo; $i++){
        $ratingStars .= "&#9733; ";
    }


    echo "<tr id=". $row['id'] .">";
    echo "<td class='lrg-tbl-row'>" . $row["hotspot-name"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='lrgz-tbl-row'>" . $row["address"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='lrg-tbl-row'>" . $row["suburb"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='sml-tbl-row'>" . $ratingStars . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<a href='<Your domain>/?id=" .$row['id'] . "'>View Details</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Dipanwita Kundu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6154505/dipanwita-kundu) said is good way to redirect to detailed form.

I have tried jquery way check out..

For example I've changed some initial conditions. Accordingly change fetch query & URL.
I suggest you to put form and table outside the loop

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
echo "<table>";
$results = array(
    array('hotspot-name'=>'hotspot1','address'=>'192.168.0.1','suburb'=>'asdf','rating'=>'5','id'=>'1'),
    array('hotspot-name'=>'hotspot2','address'=>'192.168.0.1','suburb'=>'asdf','rating'=>'4','id'=>'2'),
    array('hotspot-name'=>'hotspot3','address'=>'192.168.0.1','suburb'=>'asdf','rating'=>'3','id'=>'3'),
    array('hotspot-name'=>'hotspot4','address'=>'192.168.0.1','suburb'=>'asdf','rating'=>'2','id'=>'4')
        );

$ratingNo = 4;
foreach($results as $row){
    $ratingStars = "";
    $ratingNo = $row['rating'];

    for($i=0; $i<$ratingNo; $i++){
        $ratingStars .= "&#9733; ";
    }
    echo "<tr id=". $row['id'] .">";
    echo "<td class='lrg-tbl-row'>" . $row["hotspot-name"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='lrgz-tbl-row'>" . $row["address"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='lrg-tbl-row'>" . $row["suburb"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='sml-tbl-row'>" . $ratingStars . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name = 'Submit' value='Text'/>" . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var url = 'https://example.com'+'?id='+id; 
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor tag to redirect on details page and post the id with url on detail page and get the details of that id from your db and print them...

```
<?php 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
    $ratingStars = "";
    $ratingNo = $row[rating];

    for($i=0; $i<$ratingNo; $i++){
        $ratingStars .= "&#9733; ";
    }

    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<tr id=".$row['id'].">";
    echo "<td class='lrg-tbl-row'>" . $row["hotspot-name"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='lrgz-tbl-row'>" . $row["address"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='lrg-tbl-row'>" . $row["suburb"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='sml-tbl-row'>" . $ratingStars . "</td>";
    echo '<td class="sml-tbl-row"><a href="detail.php?id='.$row['id'].'" >More Details</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

Create a new file detail.php

```
<?php 
$id='';
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id =$_GET['id'];
    if(!empty($id))
    {
        $details = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id');
        ////here your will get all the details  
    }
}
?>
```